# Error de login usando mutacion GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

Al hacer un form para login en react usando useMutation del paquete Apollo/Client al momento de hacer el submit para el login, me sale el siguiente error:

```
Mutation error:  ApolloError: Variable "$username" of required type "String!" was not provided.
Variable "$password" of required type "String!" was not provided.
    at new ApolloError2 (index.ts:72:5)
    at QueryManager.ts:256:15
    at both (asyncMap.ts:30:30)
    at asyncMap.ts:19:47
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.then (asyncMap.ts:19:16)
    at Object.next (asyncMap.ts:31:39)
    at notifySubscription (module.js:132:18)
    at onNotify (module.js:176:3)
    at SubscriptionObserver2.next (module.js:225:5)
```

El use mutation lo uso asi:

```
const [login, {result, loading, error}] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {
    onError: err => console.log("Mutation error: ", err)
})
```

El manejo del estado de las variables lo hago con useState (la pass no está encriptada, es para demo):

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
```

y la funcion que controla el submit es esta:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    login({varibales: {username: username, password: password}})
};
```

el form está de esta manera:

```
    <form action="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            username{" "}
            <input
                type="text"
                value={username}
                onChange={({ target }) => setUsername(target.value)}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            password{" "}
            <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                id="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
            />
            <div className="mt-3">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

y por ultimo, la mutation esta definida así:

```
const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation login($username: String!, $password: String!) {
        login(username: $username, password: $password) {
            value
        }
    }
`;
```